Iterating node tree syntax. Recursion
This is the function that works as intented:
func find_node_in_tree(parent_node_ref, target_node_name):
for node in parent_node_ref.get_children():
    if temp != null:
        break
    if node.name == target_node_name:
        temp = node
        break
    else:
        if node.get_child_count() > 0:
            find_node_in_tree(node, target_node_name)
return temp

As you can see, I had to declare a global variable temp to store node reference to then pass in the return.
Here is the shorter version which returns null:
func find_node_in_tree(parent_node_ref, target_node_name):
for node in parent_node_ref.get_children():
    if node.name == target_node_name:
        return node
    else:
        if node.get_child_count() > 0:
            find_node_in_tree(node, target_node_name)

Why does the shorter version not work? With debuggion on, I can see that node is being passed in the return, but it gets lost in the main function. (NOTE: this function is in a singleton/autoload script)
Edit:
Godot Engine v4.0.2.stable.official.7a0977ce2

pretty simple. you don't return the result of your recursive function call.
As soon as any other call than the first one finds the node your searching it returns it but the return value is ignored and the previous loop continues.
So to fix you shortened function just do this:
func find_node_in_tree(parent_node_ref, target_node_name):
    for node in parent_node_ref.get_children():
        if node.name == target_node_name:
            return node
        else:
            if node.get_child_count() > 0:
                var found_node = find_node_in_tree(node, target_node_name)
                if found_node ~= null: #only stop the loop if the recursive call found the node
                     return found_node
    return null #return null if the node wasn't found in children


Oh thank you) I don't need the global variable anymore and you actually solved another problem I had :D

Too add to this. I was pretty sure that this function is implemented natively so I had to look into the documentation.
There I found find_child which will also search recursive for a node:
https://docs.godotengine.org/de/4.x/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-find-child
